# how to add subtitle and watermark on video at same time in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add subtitle and watermark in one command. How can I do that? My commands:

```
ffmpeg -i mov.mkv -sn -vf subtitles=sub.srt
ffmpeg -i mov.mkv -vf "movie=imge.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out] 0.mkv
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i image.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10,subtitles=sub.srt" -c:a copy output.mkv
```

- No need for the movie source filter: just add the image as another input.
- Join simple filters with a comma.

Comment: work put its too slow and the video give me black screen , just subtitle and watermark and audio showing .

Comment: @AbdulwahedAbuAbed Use a pastebin site to show your actual command and the complete log from the ffmpeg process, then provide the link in a comment or edit your question to include this requested information. I can't make any suggestions without it.